# Evaluation Strategies in swift

Tags: swift

**First Method

```
func show(value: Int?, or error: String) {
    if let isValue = value {
        print("Found: \(isValue)")
    } else {
        print(error)
    }
}

show(value: 5, or: "No value found")
//print "Found: 5"
```

I want to know from above code even if I found value non nil and also i have conditional code in function body, still that passing error string `no value found` will evaluated behind the scene?  the application would take the performance hit of evaluating the expression for every time we attempt to unwrap an optional?

**Second Method

```
func show(value: Int?, or error: @autoclosure () -> String) {
    if let isValue = value {
        print("Found: \(isValue)")
    } else {
        print(error())
    }
}
show(value: 5, or: "No value found")
//print "Found: 5"
```

Or this method will work, which  only evaluate the error expression when needed. Or both are same behind the scene in memory. I want answers on both method.

Comment: Don't optimise prematurely. It doesn't need to evaluate anything. It's a string _constant_.

Comment: is there any benefit of using closure instead of direct string value.

Comment: No, you are using a string constant here right? Then no.

Comment: yeah parameters are constant by default. Can you check this link https://www.swiftbysundell.com/posts/using-autoclosure-when-designing-swift-apis and go to `Passing errors as expressions`. I am little confuse about autoclosure.

Comment: There john sundell mentioned about autoclosure `we only evaluate the error expression when needed, rather than having to do it for every time we attempt to unwrap an optional.` but in that code guard statement taking care of that delay functionality not closure right. thats why i ask you about evaluation in this question with string vs @autoclosure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your explanation is correct: the first code prepares `error` string eagerly, while the second code defers string construction until it is needed.

In your situation `@autoclosure` does not give you much of an advantage, because constructing a `string` from a string literal is as inexpensive as constructing a closure.

Here is the scenario where the distinction becomes important:

```
show(value: optValue, or: "No value of \(description) found for user \(user)")
```

Now that the `error` string must be constructed by interpolating the string, the operation is no longer cheap, so deferring it with `@autoclosure` makes perfect sense. Assuming that error condition happens relatively infrequently, constructing a throw-away closure would be less expensive than interpolating the string.

Comment: yeah that just a small example to understand so I have just constructed normal string. Because I was curious about how memory deal with these kind of issues and how closure with @autoclosure attribute help to solve it. so tell me in first example memory gets allocated for that string even if we found non nil value?

Comment: @Tanzz Yes, in the first example `error` argument is constructed "eagerly", so memory is allocated for the error string. In the second example the closure is constructed, so the memory is allocated for the closure, but not for the string (unless the string is actually used).

Comment: Well well well, finally confusion clear behind normal error message vs closure(for avoiding curly braces with @autoclosure). I want some more knowledge on memory allocation just like these, string gets allocated vs just closure without string. Can you give some links on that subject  and also tell me the difference between memory is allocated for string vs closure with no string

Comment: what is the optimization difference between getting allocated by string directly vs closure(which will only produce string when needed). closure with no value will need less computation ? Beg me pardon for technical language but I am not that experienced on memory

Comment: @Tanzz I don't know of a good tutorial on this. As far as allocating a string vs. allocating a closure is concerned, closures often require less memory than strings. For strings of fixed length there is little difference, because the amount of memory being allocated has very tiny influence on the timing of code. Actual savings come when you interpolate the string, because the cost of constructing interpolated string are more significant.

Comment: ok so what mentioned in swift documentation about @autoclosure is `An autoclosure lets you delay evaluation, because the code inside isn’t run until you call the closure. Delaying evaluation is useful for code that has side effects or is computationally expensive, because it lets you control when that code is evaluated.` Now I get it correctly.

Comment: And If I use interpolated string for that error, whenever that function is going to call and trying to unwrap optional that time also the string will get allocated. It is a lot of work then but with closure at least string only evaluated when needed and just closure will get allocated in memory if value is non nil rather than interpolated string every time.

Comment: Can you tell me what evaluation strategy is it in 2nd method ? call-by-need?

Comment: @Tanzz The official name is *deferred evaluation*. Note that the closure itself is created eagerly; it’s the computation of the result of the closure that is deferred.

Comment: Oh yes in the documentation they mentioned about why to use it. I guess it is similar to lazy evaluation. so then learning evaluation strategy will help more to understand these thing? call bye value, reference , call by name, call by need. or is there some different concepts in swift?